# How to extract a substring that begins with a specific letter/character from a string?

Tags: python

For example, if I have the following string:

```
fruits = "The apples are $3.00, the oranges are $2.00, and the grapes are $10000."
```

I want to extract a list of the prices like so:

```
['$3.00', '$2.00', '$10000']
```

So far, I've done this:

```
def extract_prices(s):
    prices = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
      if s[i] == '$':
        prices.append(s[i], s.find(' '))
```

I feel like the last line is giving me problems. I don't know how to get the index for the space that comes after the price, and how to stop it there.

Any hints? Thank you for reading over this! Sorry if my explanations aren't clear.

Comment: Take a look at regex https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html module

Comment: Sorry, what part of that would be helpful? It's kind of long, and I don't know where to start :o Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Regular expressions are extremely useful for string parsing. Consider looking up a tutorial on them

Comment: You should really use regex for this, but note that `s.find` can take a second parameter that tells it were to start searching, and you could feed it `i + 1` or else it will always return the first instance of a space.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I wish I could use that method, but I haven't learned it all.. I think I'll try to edit the s.find portion of the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex:

```
>>> fruits = "The apples are $3.00, the oranges are $2.00, and the grapes are $10000."
>>> re.findall(r'(\$[\d.]+)', fruits)
['$3.00', '$2.00', '$10000.']
```

Or, if you want to be more specific to only include the `.` if there are digits:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', fruits)
['$3.00', '$2.00', '$10000']
```

Comment: Note that the last element has an extraneous period.

Comment: Could be extraneous or ambiguous!

Comment: What if it was `...and the grapes are $10000.00."`?

Comment: Agreed. Edited.

Comment: It might not be necessary to put the whole thing in a capturing group - `r'\$ ... ?'` seems to work fine.

Comment: It isn't necessary when you use `re.findall` which, by default, returns the entire match if there is no capturing group. It is without cost to include the capturing group though and I thing it serves to clarify intent. If you use one of the other Python `re` functions, you do need to include the capture group.

Answer (score 3):

Split the string and look for the dollar sign:

```
>>> fruits = "The apples are $3.00, the oranges are $2.00, and the grapes are $10000."
>>> result = [item.strip(',.!?') for item in fruits.split() if '$' in item]
>>> result
['$3.00', '$2.00', '$10000']
```

Remember to strip punctuation from each item.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
re.findall('\$\d+\.?\d+', fruits)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> re.findall('\$\d+\.?\d+', fruits)
['$3.00', '$2.00', '$10000']
```

Comment: Note that this will also match things like `$10/1`, because of the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only adjust your original code, use

```
  if s[i] == '$':
    lastPos = s.find(',', i)
    if lastPos == -1:
        lastPos = len(s)
    prices.append(s[i:lastPos])
```

instead of your lines

```
  if s[i] == '$':
    prices.append(s[i], s.find(' '))
```